# How to assign data from a subcollection to its collection and render the new object? Using react, firebase and useeffect-hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got stuck with the following and haven't found any answer after a lot of research.

**What I want to do:** simply getting users inluding their images from a firestore-DB with react and the useeffect-hook and displaying them.

The DB-structure looks as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDcrv.png

So the pictures are a **subcollection** of the users-collection.

After getting the users from the users-collection, I'm doing a second request for adding the users images to this specific user using *Object.assign*. After every forEach-run over the users-collection I'm setting the users-array with `setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, currentUser]);`. Logging the users-array shows uses INCLUDING their images.

**The problem:** When trying to render the images, they are always undefined.

Workaround: Pressing a button that calls a function for re-setting the users:

```
const reRenderUsers = () => {
    if (userDataLoaded === false) {
      setUserDataLoaded(true);
    }
    const copy = [...users];
    setUsers(copy);
  };
```

^ This solves the problem and all images where shown.

**Question:** Is there any possibility showing the images instantly without the need of "re-rendering" the users? Am I using the useEffect-hook wrong for example? I'm thankful for any advice. Many thanks in advance!

Here the full code:

```
     const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
     const [userDataLoaded, setUserDataLoaded] = useState(false);

     useEffect(() => {
       const unsubscribe = database.collection("users").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
         snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           const currentUser = {
             id: doc.id,
             ...doc.data(),
           };
           database
             .collection("users")
             .doc(currentUser.id)
             .collection("pictures")
             .get()
             .then((response) => {
               const fetchedPictures = [];
               response.forEach((document) => {
                 const fetchedPicture = {
                   id: document.id,
                   ...document.data(),
                 };
                 fetchedPictures.push(fetchedPicture);
               });
   
               currentUser.pictures = [];
               Object.assign(currentUser.pictures, fetchedPictures);
             })
             .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
             });
   
           setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, currentUser]);
         });
       });
   
       return () => {
         unsubscribe();
       };
     }, []);
   
     const reRenderUsers = () => {
       if (userDataLoaded === false) {
         setUserDataLoaded(true);
       }
       const copy = [...users];
       setUsers(copy);
     };
   
     return (
       <div>
         {!userDataLoaded ? (
           <button onClick={reRenderUsers}> load users </button>
         ) : null}
   
         {users.map((user, index) => (
           <div key={user.id}>
             {user.pictures && <img src={user.pictures[0].imageUrl}></img>}
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
     );
   }
   
   export default User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are calling setUser before the firebase response completes the callback chain. You need to update the state right after the loop inside the success callback completed. I have updated useEffect to update it right after the callback

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = database.collection("users").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const currentUser = {
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      };
      database
        .collection("users")
        .doc(currentUser.id)
        .collection("pictures")
        .get()
        .then((response) => {
          const fetchedPictures = [];
          response.forEach((document) => {
            const fetchedPicture = {
              id: document.id,
              ...document.data(),
            };
            fetchedPictures.push(fetchedPicture);
          });
          currentUser.pictures = fetchedPictures;
          setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, currentUser]);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      //dont need this here
      //setUsers((oldUsers) => [...oldUsers, currentUser]);
    });
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

Good Luck

Comment: thanks a lot! this was exactly what I was looking for :)